# Skanlite and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, scanner

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a new PC (old one died). Skanlite will not find my Kodak C310 scanner, though when I connected via USB it did discover the printer half.

The scanner worked over wifi to my old PC running Ubuntu 18, and it still works over wifi to my laptop which is running Lubuntu 19.04

Saned service is masked, and can't be unmasked, but that is the same status as on the Lubuntu laptop so probably not relevant.

Something has changed with version 20, but what?

Answer (score 0):

Something that has changed is the version of Skanlite. I uninstalled the version 2.2.0.0 that was part of the Ubuntu 20.04 bundle and installed version 2.1.0.1 from the software library. That seems to work